# python: confusion when input is coming from a pipe

Tags: python, shell, while-loop, stdin

My python script can be used in two modes:

```
./foo arg file
```

or

```
cat file | foo arg
```

This is how I decide whether stdin is a pipe or not:

```
if sys.stdin.isatty():
    print('not pipe\n')
else:
    print('is pipe')
```

and it behaves as expected:

```
./foo arg file
not pipe

cat file | ./foo arg
is pipe
```

however, in the following usage it thinks input comes from a pipe, even though the pipe is just part of the while loop:

```
while read F ; do foo arg $F ; done < /tmp/zz
is pipe
```

I am calling my script as `./foo arg file`. Why does it think input is a pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
while read F ; do foo arg $F ; done < /tmp/zz
```

You're redirecting the `while` loop's standard input from `/tmp/zz` (I'm assuming this is a file). That doesn't just include the `read` in the condition test, it includes all the statements in the body of the loop (Unless they're otherwise redirected, of course).

Your python code is only testing if standard input is a tty/terminal, and assuming that it's a pipe otherwise. But standard input can be from *any* type of open file descriptor that can be read from; tty, pipe, regular file, socket, etc.

A typical approach to accepting both filenames and standard input as a program's data is looking at the number of command line arguments; if it expects filenames but there aren't enough arguments to have any, read from standard input instead.

---

If using `bash` or `zsh` (And maybe other shells that extend basic POSIX `sh`), if you want to have a program inside a loop like this read from a script's original standard input, one technique is to redirect to a *different* descriptor than 0 (Standard input's) and tell `read` to read from it instead:

```sh
while read -r -u 3 f; do foo arg "$f" ; done 3< /tmp/zz
```

which opens the file `/tmp/zz` as descriptor number 3.

Comment: thank you, but typing the complicated construct to redirect to a different descriptor would be tedious. Is there no way to detect this in my python code? Also, please not that I cannot use number of arguments as determinant whether or not input is pipe. That would lead to chaos, if user calls with wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @400theCat surely somewhere in your program you make the determination of whether you're reading from `stdin` or a file.  Can't you save the result of that determination somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea would not work in a context where stdin is not bound to a TTY, but you nevertheless aren't in a pipe either.

In your concrete case, I would simply derive from the presenece or absence of the *file* argument, whether or not to read from stdin.

Comment: I cannot use number of arguments as determinant whether or not input is pipe. That would lead to chaos, if user calls with wrong number of arguments.

Comment: ??? Then you have to rely on heuristics: If the last argument is a valid filename, take it as a file; otherwise read from STDIN. However, the whol thing smells to me like a badly defined user interface. Another possibility, which is adopted by many programs: Take a parameter consisting of a single dash (`-`) to denote _this is not a file, but read from stdin here_.